# Assigning N number of elements from a flat list, itterativly to each member of a matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, list-comprehension

I have a flat list `message` and i have a matrix where each row contains only one element

```
final = [['K'], ['E'], ['Y']]
message = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'C', 
           'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F', 'A', 'A']
```

I want to assign every 2 letter pair from message to a single letter of final, but i want to itterate over message two letters at a time, and loop over final.

so i would get something like

```
final = [[K, F, F, C, C, B, F, C, C],
         [E, F, C, F, D, F, F, F, F],
         [Y, F, D, C, C, B, B, A, A]]
```

notice the looping effect, i need to take two elements from `message` and assign them to one of the elements of `final` after 6 element i would then go back to K and start assigning them 'looping' over `final`

after looking arround and speaking to some people in the chat i have got

`code = [[i] + list(y) for i, y in zip_longest(key, zip(*[iter(mes)] * 2),fillvalue='-')]`

however i get the wrong results i instead of filling the missing values with `-` i want to loop back over the original final matrix.

---

I get:

`[['M', 'F', 'F'], ['A', 'F', 'C'], ['R', 'F', 'D'], ['K', 'C', 'C'], ['-', 'F', 'D'], ['-', 'C', 'C'], ['-', 'B', 'F'], ['-', 'F', 'F'], ['-', 'B', 'B'], ['-', 'C', 'C'], ['-', 'F', 'F']]`

---

using cycle:

`[[i] + list(y) for i, y in zip(cycle(key), zip(*[iter(mes)] * 2))]`

results in:

`[['M', 'F', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'C'], ['R', 'B', 'C'], ['K', 'D', 'E'], ['M', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'D', 'E'], ['R', 'C', 'A'], ['K', 'E', 'D'], ['M', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'F', 'F'], ['R', 'D', 'C'], ['K', 'F', 'F'], ['M', 'E', 'B'], ['A', 'D', 'E'], ['R', 'F', 'F']]`

which is close but i just want the letters to be appended rather than repeating the letters of MARK

Comment: What looping do you need? I get the right output with `while message:
    for lst in final:
        for _ in range(2):
            lst.append(message.pop(0))`

Comment: i need to loop over key, so i assign 2 element, then go to E, assign 2 elements then Y assign 2 elements an then bakc to K and repeat

Comment: The reason why these answere wernt working is cause i made final a 1 Dimensional list where as it it needs to be a dimension per letter. ill fix that give a one of these methods a try an upvote people for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to over-complicate this. Try, simply:

```
final = [['K'], ['E'], ['Y']]
message = ['F', 'F', 'F', ...]
while message:
    for lst in final:
        for _ in range(2):
            lst.append(message.pop(0))
```

This gives me the result you are looking for.

If you really must use a list comprehension, you could go for something like:

```
final = [final[index] + reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, 
                               list(message[i:i+2] for i in 
                                    range(index,
                                          len(message), 
                                          2 * len(final))))
         for index in range(len(final))]
```

But that is really more list incomprehension.

Comment: what is lst? i am get .append is no attribute of lst, but i am guessing thats just cause i dont know what lst is

Comment: `lst` is the loop variable I'm assigning each `list` in `final` to.

Comment: sorry i realised that, when my brain wakes up an i get this implemeneted ill accept

Comment: haha i accept your answer but i am just having trouble implementing it

Comment: This method works except that when the list become empty it still trys to pop, which results in a Index Error

Comment: Thwart was not an issue with the example you gave. You will have to handle this error, perhaps by consuming a copy of `message` so the original is still available to loop. You will need to decide when to stop; `cycle` would continue indefinitely if allowed.

Comment: its a 2 stage cypher and my requirements state: the key should be devisible by the message, when this requirement is true i have no issue, so i need to use regex to define max/min key and message sizes

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
from itertools import izip, izip_longest, cycle

final = [['K'],
         ['E'],
         ['Y']]
message = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F', 'A', 'A']

by_2 = izip_longest(*[iter(message)]*2, fillvalue='-')
for fin_list, vals in izip(cycle(final), by_2):
    fin_list.extend(vals)

# [['K', 'F', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'C'], ['E', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], ['Y', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A']]
```

Comment: again str object has no attribute .extend i dont understand why fin_list is always a string when it should be a list

Comment: @alko it modifies `final` inplace

Comment: @JonClements yep, just found out

Comment: the error was related to my final being a 1 dimensional string rather than a matrix!

Answer (score 1):

How about a good old while loop?

```
i = 0
while i < len(message):
    for part in range(3):
        final[part].append(message[i])
        final[part].append(message[i + 1])
        i += 2
```

This code should be quite literally able to be copied and pasted into your code. Sometimes `while` loops are just way simpler than `for` loops, and I love to use them. This code simply goes through each part of the `final` and adds two from message for each one, and the `while` loop takes care of doing this until all the message has been copied into final appropriately.